# for i in var statement does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, binary

I am creating a Binary to Decimal converter. I am trying to check for validity of user input by only allowing the program to continue if the input contains only zeroes and ones. This is what I have so far:

```
while valueCheck == False:
    value = input ("Please enter the binary value to convert to a decimal value.")
    for i in value:
        if not (i in "01"):
            print("Please enter only zeroes and ones.")
            break
        else:
            valueCheck = True
```

The user enters an input, and if it is valid, `valueCheck` is set to `True` which terminates the loop and the program continues. If the input is not valid, `valueCheck` remains `False` and the user will be asked for input again.

However, the `if not` check does not work as expected. It only works if the invalid character(s) are in index `0` of input.

For example:

- Input: `5111` Output: `Please enter only zeroes and ones` and user asked for input again.
- Input: `1115` Output: `Please enter only zeroes and ones` and program continues with invalid characters. The program should not be continuing.

I understand that this is happening because the for loop starts from the left most index value and checks that. Which is why if the first element contains an invalid character, the output will be as expected. If the first element contains a valid character, then the program moves onto `else` and terminates the loop?

How can I get the program to continue the `while` loop until all characters in input are only zeroes and ones regardless of their position in `value`?

Comment: Another way to do the same thing `if all(i in '01' for i in value):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you set `valueCheck` to `True` after the first check, as you said.

You can just take advantage of the `else` clause in the `for` loop here that executes if no `break`s have occurred, i.e unindent the `else` clause:

```
while valueCheck == False:
    value = input ("Please enter the binary value to convert to a decimal value.")
    for i in value:
        if not (i in "01"):
            print("Please enter only zeroes and ones.")
            break
    else:
        valueCheck = True
```

Comment: Ah, works as expected now. Thank you. So this means that if an invalid character is found, rather than going directly to the `else` statement, it will go back to the IF statement first and keep doing that until all elements have been checked. Then once all elements have been checked, it'll go to the else statement as long as none of the IF tests are true?

Comment: @AugustWilliams The `else` clause of the `for` loop is pretty straight-forward to grok after you've played with it: if a `break` is executed while the loop is running, `else` isn't executed. If no `break`s occur, it runs. If an invalid character is found, the loop *ends* w/o the `else` getting executed, thereby resulting in the `while` condition being the same. If no characters are invalid, the `else` clause is executed, changing `valueCheck` making the condition in `while` fail.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

You set `valueCheck` to `True` when processing the first `1` and never change it. My suggestion would be (maybe not the greatest style but fewest changes to the logic of your code):

set `valueCheck` to `False` before breaking the for-loop